# How does the biuld task of a UWP App on azure Pipelines knows the name of the certificate to use?

Tags: uwp, certificate, azure-pipelines-build-task

When building a UWP app on Azure Pipelines, I had an error about the .pfx file not found. My pfx had another name.

Hence my questions:

- how does the build task know what pfx file to take? Is there a naming convention?
- Can I explictly specify another file to use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Package.appxmanifest file of the UWP app has a Packaging tab where we can specify the package. This is how the association is made and hence how the build task knows which cert file to use.